# How to position a div inside another div with existing content to serve as background? z-index issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A div (lets call it the "master" div) exists with some content and I have no control over its content other than knowing that there will be no explicit z-index CSS set on the elements placed in it.  However, I do have control over the master div's CSS. I want to place another div inside the master div to serve as its background. You may ask: Why not set the background CSS of the master div? Because I want to pick the content of the master div to be saved and restored later without having the master div's CSS at that time.

Here is a simple case:

```
     <div class="master" style="position:relative;z-index:25;">
           abcde <div id="someotherDiv">bla.. bla... bla</div>
     </div>
```

I want to put a div inside it to serve as its background. So, this is what I tried:

```
   $('<div class="background" style="position:absolute;width:100%; height:100%;z-index:1;left:0px;top:0px;color:red;"></div>').appendTo('.master');
```

When I do so, it hides the string "abcde" as the absolute positioned "background" div is placed on top of it.

z-index is not as simple as it appears... The stacking order, the inheriting from the container div, need to "position" all play a role in this. I tried many other approaches but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative z-index for the background container should work.

```html
    <div class="master">
      abcde<div id="someotherDiv">bla.. bla... bla</div>
      <div class="background"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
    .master {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 25;
    }

    .background {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      left:0;
      top: 0;
      background: yellow;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgxbNG

Comment: shouldn't the background div position be fixed ? to avoid issue when scrolling